# Extract Software Signing Cert using Python from a PE File

Tags: python, openssl, portable-executable, pyopenssl, python-cryptography

When trying to extract the cert from a PE file using `cryptography`, it fails with `ValueError: Unable to load certificate`. I am able to properly extract the cert from the same PE file using `subprocess` and the `openssl` command line. I want to understand what is going wrong in the version of the code that uses `cryptography`.

I'm using Python 3.7.1, cryptography 2.4.2, and pefile 2018.8.8

```
import pefile
from cryptography import x509
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend

pe = pefile.PE(fname)
pe.parse_data_directories(directories=[pefile.DIRECTORY_ENTRY['IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_SECURITY']])
sigoff = 0
siglen = 0
for s in pe.__structures__:
    if s.name == 'IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_SECURITY':
        sigoff = s.VirtualAddress
        siglen = s.Size
pe.close()
with open(fname, 'rb') as fh:
    fh.seek(sigoff)
    thesig = fh.read(siglen)
cert = x509.load_der_x509_certificate(thesig[8:], default_backend())
```

This fails with `ValueError: Unable to load certificate`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the problem is that the signature is a PKCS7 object. MS has documented it in a [Word](http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/c/5/9c5b2167-8017-4bae-9fde-d599bac8184a/authenticode_pe.docx). I have not found a PDF version yet...

So you need to parse the PKCS7 object first. I use [asn1crypto](https://github.com/wbond/asn1crypto/) for this.

This works for me:

```
import pefile
from cryptography import x509
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend

from asn1crypto import cms

pe = pefile.PE(fname)
sigoff = pe.OPTIONAL_HEADER.DATA_DIRECTORY[pefile.DIRECTORY_ENTRY["IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_SECURITY"]].VirtualAddress
siglen = pe.OPTIONAL_HEADER.DATA_DIRECTORY[pefile.DIRECTORY_ENTRY["IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_SECURITY"]].Size
pe.close()

with open(fname, 'rb') as fh:
    fh.seek(sigoff)
    thesig = fh.read(siglen)

signature = cms.ContentInfo.load(thesig[8:])

for cert in signature["content"]["certificates"]:
    parsed_cert = x509.load_der_x509_certificate(cert.dump(), default_backend())
    print(parsed_cert)
```